# Does ADT support Java 8 API?

Tags: java, android, adt

Do Android Developers Tools support JAVA 8 API up to this date? I'm trying to build an Android app using JAVA 8 and I was wondering about this thing.

Comment: Not officially. Xav Ducrohet was asked that in the Google I|O 2014 "Android Fireside Chat" presentation, and he declined to answer, more or less.

Comment: It **barely supports Java 7** (only API Level 19 supports certain Java 7 features)...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467933/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-in-eclipse-android-project/24468106

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 APIs started becoming available in Android API 26 (which is Android 8, or Nougat). A mechanism called [API desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) is available to use [certain Java 8 APIs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) on earlier Android versions, regardless of the Android API level.

However, there is no 1:1 connection between Android and Java API versions. In the past, it has taken Google some 2–3 years following the release of a new Java version to gradually start implementing its APIs. So, the question “is a certain Java API available on a certain Android version” can only be answered on a per-class/member base. You will have to look up every class, method, constant etc. on the **Android** API reference and see if it it supported, and what the minimum API version on Android is – or see if API desugaring provides it, which is not tied to a particular Android API level.